WooCommerce Products Custom Sorting and Pagination issue
Is there a way to resolve pagination issues within WooCommerce when custom sorting products? I have custom product meta for width, such as 2.5 ; multiple products might have this same width value. The problem is I might product XYZ on page 1 and then click on page 2 and see product XYZ again.
I have the below code, which works well for sorting, but does not result in unique pagination. I've tried adding a distinct value, sorting by decimal width and then the product name to give it a second sort criteria but nothing works.
If anyone has any ideas around unique product pagination I'd really appreciate it.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_custom_sorting_option' );

function add_custom_sorting_option( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['decimalwidth_asc'] = 'Width: Ascending';
    $sortby['decimalwidth_desc'] = 'Width: Descending';
    return $sortby;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_sorting_query_args', 10, 3 );

function custom_sorting_query_args( $args, $orderby, $order ) {
    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'decimalwidth_asc':
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['order'] = 'ASC';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
            break;
        case 'decimalwidth_desc':
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['order'] = 'DESC';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
            break;
    }
    return $args;
}


add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'custom_sorting_float_meta_query', 10, 6 );

function custom_sorting_float_meta_query( $sql, $queries, $type, $primary_table, $primary_id_column, $context ) {
    if ( ! empty( $context->query_vars['orderby'] ) && $context->query_vars['orderby'] == 'meta_value_num' ) {
        if ( ! empty( $context->query_vars['meta_key'] ) && $context->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'decimalwidth' ) {
            $sql['orderby'] = str_replace( 'ORDER BY', 'ORDER BY CAST(' . $primary_table . '.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2))', $sql['orderby'] );
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby($default_orderby) {
    return 'decimalwidth_asc';
}

function custom_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));
    
    if ($orderby_value == 'decimalwidth_asc') {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
    }
    
    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_catalog_orderby_options');

function custom_catalog_orderby_options($sortby) {
    unset($sortby['popularity']);
    unset($sortby['date']);
    unset($sortby['price']);
    unset($sortby['price-desc']);
    return $sortby;
}


One way to avoid this is probably adding a second sort case 'decimalwidth_asc': $args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ); $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth'; break; try it like this.
